# Ajax form posting not working - never seems to submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I see this question in various forms many times, but looking at as many examples as I can and I can't figure out why my code won't work.

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){


    $('datafixForm').submit(function( e ) {

        var formData = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'process.php',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Form submitted!');
                console.log('Recieved' + data);
                alert('Form submitted!');
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('We failed');
                console.log('Got' + data);
                alert('Didnt worky!');
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault();
        e.unbind();
    });
    $('datafixForm').submit(); // Submit the form
});
</script>
```

Is my submission script however it never get either of the success or error console logs or alerts appearing.

I've checked in chromes network monitor and no post request is shown there either. There is various types of data in the form, including a multiple file selection, however I don't think this should be an issue at all.

Comment: should it be $('#datafixForm') instead of $('datafixForm')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your form having the ID datafixForm? Because then your selector should be `$('#datafixForm')` instead of simply `$('datafixForm')`.

Also I've seen the starting part is `$(document).ready(function)` generally rather than `$('document').ready(function)`(document is not generally referred as a string) but I'm not 100% sure if this would cause a problem.

EDIT: The $(document) bit as noted in the comments isn't really a problem, more of an observation. Apparently both ways are valid!

Comment: The document bit has been working prior. I just included it incase people thought I didn't have it at all. Thanks - your fix works and I'm just waiting 6 min to accept it :) - I've been working on this all day now and was getting aggravated at why I wasn't getting either alert box - once you pointed it out, it was obvious! :D

Comment: Okay good to know! I was doubtful on the document part, learned something new today.

Comment: Do you want to edit to say while it's not the cause of the problem it is something to note?

Comment: Added a little clarification in an edit, is that what you meant?

Comment: Yup, brill :) and finally I can accept as an answer too.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the right selector. Currently datafixForm is not a class nor an id.

**ID**

```
#datafixForm
```

**Class**

```
.datafixForm
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your `e.preventDefault();` to the top of the Submit event.